# Select files within list of files imported with glob

Tags: python, file, glob

I am importing a list of files with glob with this code:

```
fileList = glob.glob('./final_clim/*.shp')
```

I then need to loop through this selecting certain files and running a loop through these. I have tried editing the string or using list comprehension but I have 2 sets of numbers in the filename and can't work out how to do this. Example file names are:

gla14_eco_23_clim_23

gla14_eco23_clim_24

gla14_eco24_clim_23

So I need all the 'eco23' files grouped together in order to run some code and then 'eco24' but I have hundreds of 'ecos'so can't just split manually.

I have tried:

```
for file in fileList:
    eco = [f for f in fileList if ("eco_23", f)
```

I have tried using re.findall but can't quite work it out

I have also tried:

```
for file in fileList:
    hd, tl = path.split(file)
    name = tl.replace('gla14_eco_', "") etc..
```

I can't seem to work out how to do this. I could potentially use a dict to replace the last 2 numbers with letters to maybe make this easier? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list comprehension needs correction I believe.

```
for i in range(0,825):
    eco = [f for f in fileList if 'eco_'+str(i)+'_' in f]
```

Comment: Great thanks, how do I replace '23' with for each number between 0 and 824? To clarify my code needs to select all the files with eco_23 and run some code, then all the files with eco_24 then eco_25 etc...

Comment: @HeatherKay : I have edited my answer to your new requirement. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks so much, will play around with it and see, any problems will let you know.

Comment: When I run this the " if 'eco_'+str(i) " part is picking up single integers. For example it will pick up eco_2, eco_12, eco_23, eco_24, eco_251, eco_342 etc. for i=2

Comment: Edited again. Please check

Comment: Yes, this seems to be working on my smaller selection of files. Thanks again, I am just a beginner and it is great to see the logic of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all your eco23 etc., you could loop through and use this:

```
for i in range(0,825):
    fileList = glob.glob('./final_clim/*eco_'+str(i)+'*.shp')
```

Comment: The point is I have hundreds of eco files. I need to load all eco_23 and run some code then all eco_24 then all eco_25 etc from 0 to 826. I don't want to have to rewrite my code 826 times.

Comment: Yep but as with nitin3685's answer you can achieve this with a minor change. Personally, I find this a lot easier to understand!